# Calcular pares números introducidos (error sin sentido)

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JS desde hace poco y haciendo algunos ejercicios. En este me he quedado atascado porque no encuentro sentido a lo que me sucede.
 El código siguiente me funciona perfectamente salvo cuando el 1er número que introduzco es 15 y el segundo 2...
 El alert me salta "Hay un total de 0 números pares entre los dos números seleccionados"

En qué me equivoco?

```
<script>
    var numero1 = prompt("Facilíteme el primer número");
    var numero2 = prompt("Facilíteme el segundo número");
    var total = 0;

    if(numero1 < numero2){
        var chico = numero1;
        var grande = numero2;
    }
    if(numero2 < numero1){
        var chico = numero2;
        var grande = numero1;
    }

    var tipo = (chico%2) ? "Impar" : "Par";
    console.log(chico);
    if(tipo == "Par"){
        while(chico < grande){
            document.write(total);
            total = total + 1;
            chico = parseInt(chico) + 2;
        }
    }else{
        while(grande > chico){
            //document.write(total);
            total = total + 1;
            grande = parseInt(grande) - 2;
            console.log(chico);
        }
    }


    alert(`Hay un total de ${total - 1} números pares entre los dos números seleccionados`);

</script>
```

Comment: los console.log los he estado usando para comrpobar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La entrada del usuario es una cadena. Si el usuario escribe 2 y 15, tendrás que `numero1` es la cadena `"2"` y `numero2` es la cadena `"15"`.

Cuando compares `numero1<numero2`, se están comparando cadenas, y estas se hacen en "orden alfabético". Por tanto `"15"` será menor que `"2"`, porque en un diccionario aparecería antes (al ser la primera "letra", que es `"1"`, anterior a `"2"`).

A partir de ahí no es de extrañar que te salgan resultados sorprendentes. Debes convertirlos a entero con `parseInt()` tan pronto como los leas con `prompt()`, por ejemplo así:

```
var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("Facilíteme el primer número"));
var numero2 = parseInt(prompt("Facilíteme el segundo número"));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Abulafia!